# Change center of rotation of the marker in MAPBOX

Tags: javascript, mapbox-gl-js

this code moves the marker around one point (for Africa), I need to change to a custom location. Somebody help me please. Thanks

```
var marker = new mapboxgl.Marker();

    function animateMarker(timestamp) {
        var radius = 20;

        // Update the data to a new position based on the animation timestamp. The
        // divisor in the expression `timestamp / 1000` controls the animation speed.
        marker.setLngLat([
            Math.cos(timestamp / 1000) * radius,
            Math.sin(timestamp / 1000) * radius
        ]);

        // Ensure it's added to the map. This is safe to call if it's already added.
        marker.addTo(map);

        // Request the next frame of the animation.
        requestAnimationFrame(animateMarker);
    }

    // Start the animation.
    requestAnimationFrame(animateMarker);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to modify the `marker.setLngLat()` function to offset the marker's longitude and latitude to match your preferred location. See Mapbox [documentation](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/#marker#setlnglat).

For example, the code snippet below will animate the marker around Jakarta, Indonesia.

```
  marker.setLngLat([
    Math.cos(timestamp / 1000) * radius + 106.8,
    Math.sin(timestamp / 1000) * radius - 6.2
  ]);
```

Full CodePen [here](https://codepen.io/pj_leonard/pen/PoqyQVE).

Disclaimer: I work at Mapbox

Comment: Thanks, if the solution is very simple